# Insert comment based on existing data

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a little problem, with my VBA code. I have made a userform, which has following:
Combobox1 is Sku number
Combobox2 is Test number
Combobox3 is Test result
Textbox is Comment_To_Result.

```
       'Inserts comments og test result
   Dim iRow, iCol
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data sheet")
  iCol = Application.Match(CLng(ComboBox2.Value), .Columns("Q"), 0)
  iCol = Application.Match(CLng(ComboBox1.Value), .Columns("A"), 0)



'  If IsError(iRow) Then MsgBox "SKU not found": Exit Sub
'  If IsError(iCol) Then MsgBox "Test number not found": Exit Sub

  'Add test result/next step and comment
  .Cells(iCol, 30).Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value
  .Cells(iCol, 30 + 1).Value = Me.Comments_To_Result.Value
End With
```

I want the code to find sku number and test number and based on that, insert test result and comment i the same row. (SKU and test number is already in the sheet)
    The code below is working fine, when the test number is 1, but when i try to change the test number to for example 2 or 3, the column code is debuggen. Does anybody know, what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have two worksheets, or only one? Is `Worksheets("Data sheet")` something else than the `ActiveSheet`?

Comment: No, it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing results in the same columns (30 and 31) regardless of the result of the search on the `Test number` column. You probably want this:

```
Dim iRow, iCol
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data sheet")
  iRow = Application.Match(CLng(ComboBox1.Value), .Columns("A"), 0)
  iCol = Application.Match(CLng(ComboBox2.Value), .Rows(17), 0)

  If IsError(iRow) Then MsgBox "SKU not found": Exit Sub
  If IsError(iCol) Then MsgBox "Test number not found": Exit Sub

  'Add test result/next step and comment
  .Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = Me.ComboBox3.Value
  .Cells(iRow, iCol+1).Value = Me.Comments_To_Result.Value
End With
```

p.s.: Sincde the items searched for are numbers (integers), I converted the combo's values to numbers before searching them in the worksheet:

```
  CLng(ComboBox1.Value) and CLng(ComboBox2.Value)
' ^^^^^                     ^^^^^
```

Comment: It is still debuggen at: iCol=. Rows("17")... Thanks for helping.

Comment: @broder123 that means the `ComboBox1.Value` was not found in the row.

Comment: Thanks for helping A.S.H, but it is still not working. I tried the modifed code , but now it says that "SKU not found", unless the sku number is in the data sheet.

Comment: @broder123 so both the SKU and Test are numbers. Integers, right? We need to convert the combox values to numbers before applying the search (using `CLng(...)`. Try the modified code.

Comment: Yes, both are numbers. The code is only working on SKU, and not Test Number. So when i use Test number 1 it is working (only because it is in a higher row than 2), but if i use 2 it's doesn't work. I have changed the orginal code, to yours, just with .Columns at Combobox2.